# PrimeFaces Barcode does not work?

Tags: maven, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, barcode

I am trying to get the Barcode from the [PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/barcode.xhtml) running, but when I place the XHTML code and let it run in my local Wildfly 8, I just get total rubbish. The numbers of every barcode are too big and the QR code does not work at all.

I believe I might have a missing Maven dependency, but I am having trouble to find the necessary one.

Following the documentation, I think I have to integrate the dependency for `barcode4j-light` in the version `2.1`, but I can't find this version on Maven.

How would I have to integrate this? I'd appreciate every help! Thanks in advance!

My Barcode.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head/>
    <h:body>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Interleaved 2 of 5" />
            <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="int2of5" />

            <h:outputText value="Codabar" />
            <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="codabar"/>

            <h:outputText value="Code39" />
            <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="code39" />

            <h:outputText value="Code128" />
            <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="code128"/>

            <h:outputText value="EAN-8" />
            <p:barcode value="20123451" type="ean8"/>

            <h:outputText value="EAN-13" />
            <p:barcode value="0123456789012" type="ean13"/>

            <h:outputText value="UPC-A (PNG)" />
            <p:barcode value="01234567895" type="upca" format="png"/>

            <h:outputText value="UPC-E (Vertical)" />
            <p:barcode value="01234133" type="upce" orientation="90"/>

            <h:outputText value="PDF417" />
            <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="pdf417"/>

            <h:outputText value="DataMatrix" />
            <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="datamatrix"/>

            <h:outputText value="Postnet" />
            <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="postnet"/>

            <h:outputText value="QR" />
            <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="qr"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.glasses</groupId>
    <artifactId>primeWork</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>primeWork</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I'm with your same problem right now, so I can see the barcode images, but their digits at the bottom are too big. It only happens to me when I use the `p:barcode` component in the project which I'm working in. In a project built from scratch there's no problem with it, so it seems to be related with some related library conflicts.. So difficult to find where the problem is :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So `barcode4j-light-2.1` isn't available in the Maven Repository. We need to download it from the [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/barcode4j/?source=typ_redirect). Once you download it and unzip it, go the `build` dir. The `barcode4j-light` jar will be there.

To install it to your local Maven repo, follow [these instructions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html). Basically, from the command line (from the `build` dir and assuming you have Maven installed) :

```
C:\...build>mvn install:install-file -Dfile=barcode4j-light.jar 
                                     -DgroupId=net.sf.barcode4j
                                     -DartifactId=barcode4j-light 
                                     -Dversion=2.1 
                                     -Dpackaging=jar
```

That command should be all on one line and not line separated as you see here. Then you can just add the dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcode4j-light</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You will also need this one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
    <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>  <!-- QR code support -->
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Not step by step like this, but this is described in the [Prime Faces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation). It worked for me, once I followed the above steps.

Comment: That could be valid for `qrgen` dependency, as the OP suggests the QR support doesn't work. However, he tells he can see the rest of barcodes, but unproperly formatted.

Comment: Both dependencies are now available on Maven and works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I also have added to my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
        <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Who resolve the dependencie problem in NB8 Maven Web Projects.